# phantomjs failing to load modules into page

Tags: phantomjs

I'm trying to use phantomjs. Simple examples like getting the title of the webpage are working. But, when I try to source a script into my webpage under test it doesn't seem to run the code.

Here's my phantomjs test script:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://localhost:8000/', function(status) {
    if(status === "success") {
        setTimeout(function(){
            page.render('example.png');
            phantom.exit();
        },1000);
    }
});
```

Here's the webpage that is returned by localhost:8000.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='/bundle.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id='a-button'>A button</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Bundle.js is created by browserify and contains this file:

```
let $ = require('jquery');
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('<div id="ready">Ready</div>').appendTo('body');
});
```

When I run this setup in a browser I see the button and I see "Ready" as expected.

When I run this under phantomjs and look at example.png I only see the button, it never seems to run the code that is in the bundle.js file.

Comment: PhantomJS doesn't (yet) support ES-2015.

Comment: @vaviloff. Thank you. It was that "let" instead of "var" on the require